# SPServices returning no items

Tags: sharepoint-online, spservices

I'm using a `SPServices` operation form to get list items. The code is as below:

```
NWF$().SPServices({
   operation: "GetListItems",
   async: false,
   listName: "listname",
   CAMLQuery: "<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ID'/><Value Type='Number'>1</Value></Eq></Where></Query>",
   completefunc: function(xData, Status) 
   {                     
      NWF$(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each  (function() {
        var title = ($(this).attr("ows_Title"));                 
      });
   }
});
```

But I am unable to get items because `xData.responseXML` is empty.